# Please I need help: to find online Ruth Cantillation (teamim) of Livorno tradition. Maybe in some University department (Ramat Aviv ,Givat Ram)?

Tags: minhag, internet, trop-cantillation

Is it possible to find online (audio to listen) Cantillation of biblical book : Ruth,  for specific Livorno traditional music? Maybe in some University department (like Ramat Aviv or Givat Ram)? Or Maybe in some jewish seminary in USA? If someone know please tell me.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Demio!

Comment: Do they not have it at www.torah.it?

Comment: Thank you Mauro for good suggestion; "www.torah.it" is very very full of intersting things; but in this case I'm sorry I didn't find it.

Comment: Why don't you ask them directly? (I have seen Ruth in an old machzor from Livorno with Ladino translation BTW) http://moked.it/livornoebraica/contatti/

Comment: Another possibility is the Leo Levi collection http://www.jewish-music.huji.ac.il/content/leo-levy